# Как получить feature points каскадом Хаара при помощи Emgu CV?

Tags: c#, emgucv

Я разрабатываю проект по распознаванию эмоций лица, используя библиотеку Emgu CV. Моя программа может находить лицо, глаза, рот и нос, но теперь мне нужны feature points для распознавания эмоций.

[image: вот эти точки мне нужны]